# Is the fact that $e^{ix}$ and $\cos(x) + i \sin(x)$ have the same derivative and a point in common enough to imply they’re equal

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, complex-numbers

If we let
$$f(x) = e^{ix}$$
and
$$g(x) = \cos(x) + i \sin(x),$$
then
\begin{align*}
f(0) &= g(0) = 1,\\
f’(x) &= if(x),\\
g’(x) &= ig(x).
\end{align*}
Is this enough to imply they’re the same - is it possible for any other function $k(x)$ to take the form $k’(x) = i\ k(x)$ and where $k(0) = 1$.

Comment: Yes it is. You need to make sure your proof of global uniqueness for a linear ODE carries over to the complex category though, which isn't necessarily obvious.

Comment: Well, we don't know they have the "same derivative." But we know they satisfy the same differential equation. And yes, it is enough, but you have to know a result from differential equations.

Answer (score 1):

It is true and  it in this case it is easy to prove without digging too much into ODE theory. Assume
$$\tag{1}
f'(x) = if(x),~~f(0)=1
$$
for differentiable $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. It is important that it is defined on the connected set $\mathbb{C}$. Note:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\exp(-ix)f(x) = \exp(-ix)f'(x) -i\exp(-ix)f(x) = i\exp(-ix)f(x)-i\exp(-ix)f(x) = 0
$$
So $x \mapsto \exp(-ix) f(x) $ is equal to some constant $c$. The constant $c$ must be 1 because of $f(0)=1$.  So we can rearrange for every $x \in \mathbb{C}$:
$$
\exp(-ix)f(x) =1 \implies f(x) = \exp(ix)
$$
So every function that satisfies $(1)$ must be equal to $x \mapsto \exp(ix)$.